# upload video from wordpress to youtube channel then fetch the video to web

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube-api, content-management-system

In my WordPress website. I want to upload a video from my WordPress side to YouTube channel, then I  want to fetch and show the same embedded video on my website also.
please guide me how can i achieve this. best regards.

Comment: This is not a place to come and ask for full-on tutorials. This question is currently simply way too broad to be asked here.

Answer (score 0):

then you can just upload all your videos to youtube and then from there you can show that to your Wordpress website. ( using embed or directly using the link with any widget )